# R - Problems with legends and histograms

Tags: r, histogram, legend

I am having problems with displaying the legend on each graph.
[Overlapping Histograms on one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8crP.png)

I would like to have a legend on the topright corner for each. However, with the command line I use, I get this zoomed in version.

```
 par(mfrow = c(2,2))

#plot histograms on one same graph 
hist(DSA, prob=TRUE, main="Controls", xlab="Sizes (um)", ylab="Frequency", col="yellowgreen",xlim= c(5,25), ylim=c(0,0.5), breaks=10)
hist(DSB, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),add=T)
hist(DSC, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0.8,0,1,0.5),add=T)
box()

plot_colors <- c("yellowgreen","blue", "pink")
legend(x = "topright",inset = 0,
       legend = c("1", "2", "3"), 
       col=plot_colors, lwd=6, cex=0.5,horiz = FALSE)
```

Any ideas? Thanks! I have changed the lwd and the cex, to many combinations, but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: thank you very much! I am quite new at this

Comment: Please provide your data `DSA`, `DSB` and `DSC` so we can reproduce your plots. You can do this by copy and pasting the output of `dput(DSA)`, etc.

Comment: btw, this code only produces one plot out of the four as shown in your picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP only provided code for one of the four plots as shown in the picture, so I will just work with that, but one can just easily apply the following solution to all legends:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

# Some madeup data
DSA = rnorm(10000, 15, 2)
DSB = rnorm(10000, 17, 3)
DSC = rnorm(10000, 13, 1)


#plot histograms on one same graph 
hist(DSA, prob=TRUE, main="Controls", xlab="Sizes (um)", ylab="Frequency", col="yellowgreen",xlim= c(5,25), ylim=c(0,0.5), breaks=10)
hist(DSB, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),add=T)
hist(DSC, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0.8,0,1,0.5),add=T)
box()

plot_colors <- c("yellowgreen","blue", "pink")
legend(x = "topright",inset = 0,
       legend = c("1", "2", "3"), 
       col=plot_colors, lwd=6, cex=0.7,horiz = FALSE, y.intersp=0.6, bty="n")
```

[image]

Basically, I reduced the `y.intersp` to 0.6 so that the y spacing between legend keys is reduced. I then set `cex=0.7` (which is greater than `cex=0.5`) to make it more readable after the spacing shrinkage. The optional `bty = "n"` argument removes the boarder of the legend, which is more presentable, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions, I had to decrease y.intersp to 0.1 and cex=0.4, and it works. Thanks you for your help!

Comment: @Orbis If you think that this answers your question, feel free to accept it so others can see!